# Simple Jquery Css style calls

Tags: jquery, css

Whats wrong with this?

```
var hover = $('<img />').attr('src', hovers[i]).css('position', 
                                                        'absolute', 
                                                        'visibility' , 
                                                        'hidden');
```

for some reason the `'visibility' , 'hidden'` does not get called? but if i remove the position style it does.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to pass an object with key value pairs into the css method rather then passing extra arguments:

```
var hover = $('<img />')
    .attr('src', hovers[i])
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        visibility: 'hidden'
    });
```

See the documentation here for ".css(map)": http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/css/

from the css docs you can see that your syntax is not correct, when define mulitple css attributes use :, then comma to separate, also enclose all the attributes in curly brackets, like this:

```
var hover = $('<img />').attr('src', hovers[i]).css({'position':'absolute','visibility':'hidden'});
```

Comment: It isn't enough to add colons... What you are really doing is passing an object as the single argument and arguments are defined inside of curly braces. Take another look at the documentation you linked, where they explain .css(map)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
    var hover = $('<img />').attr('src', hovers[i]).css({'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden'});
```